# Why does API Gateway give 403 Error when no authorization is set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-502

I have an api in API Gateway with path /report & there's a resource in in with path /report/{reportId}. Both of them can receive ANY request.

The way the app is designed is to first hit the /report endpoint to create a report & then hit the /report/{reportId} endpoint to fetch the report.

The app works fine when the first endpoint is hit. However, when the /report/{reportId} is hit, I constantly receive either a 403 or a 502 error. But mostly a 403 error. This is weird since the "Authorization" is "NONE" & "API Key Required" is set to "False". I haven't enabled any IAM authentication either.

I'm not sure why these errors are coming up.